# Adjusting css gradient background

Tags: css, gradient

Is it possible to amend/adjust a gradient background so the fade starts lower done. Example, see the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/gZgLc/5/

Let's say for example I wanted the white ti start to fade in at the '123test' text, how would I do this?

HTML

```
<div id="main">
<div class="feature-box">
  <div class="feature-box-tab">
    <div class="slide" style="height:250px;">

            <div class="inner">
                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="single-feature-top">
    <p>123test. 123test<br><br>
</div>
<br>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main {
width:958px;
position:relative;
top:-9px;
background:#FF9900 url(../images/core/header.png) no-repeat center top;
border:1px solid #dadada;
border-top:none;
border-bottom:2px solid #dadada;
-webkit-border-radius:8px;
-moz-border-radius:8px;
-ms-border-radius:8px;
-o-border-radius:8px;
border-radius:8px;
margin:0 auto 25px;
background: #fff;
background: url('linear-gradient.png') 0 0 repeat-x;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #FF9900);
```

Comment: Do you mean on the fly, or just changing the CSS so it is always different? If you just want to know what the proper syntax is... I suggest just using this tool: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Yeah, i just meant permanently so the gradient is where I want it to begin all the time. I don't want it to change. thanks, I'll check out the link

Comment: Can you add a #background `div` behind #main?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on gradients? E.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: What @RoToRa says, read the part about color stops, which allow you to specify position for each color (you can have the same color at 0% and 70% for instance). Alternatively, if you want the gradient only on the `.single-feature-top` you could just apply it to that instead? http://jsfiddle.net/gZgLc/8/

Comment: Use http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definately ... You have to use percentages for that.

[***Solution***](http://jsfiddle.net/gZgLc/9/)

All the code was generated from this website.[**Source Website**](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

CSS added.

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%,#fff 75% #ff9900 80%, #ff9900 100% );
/* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fff),color-stop(70%, #fff), color-stop(80%, #ff9900),  color-stop(100%, #ff9900));
/* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%,#fff 75%, #ff9900 80%, #ff9900 100%);
/* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%,#fff 75%, #ff9900 80%,  #ff9900 100%);
/* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%,#fff 75%, #ff9900 80%, #ff9900 100%);
/* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%,#fff 75%, #ff9900 80%, #ff9900 100%, #ff9900 100%, #ff9900 100%);
/* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#eded2f', endColorstr='#ff9900', GradientType=0);
/* IE6-8 */
```

***EDIT:*** Also remember that this may not work exactly the same on older IE browsers(IE6-8).

***EDIT2***: Changed colours in the fiddle to reflect your desired colours

Comment: You don't *have* to use percentages, any length unit (like `px`, `em` etc) will work too.

Comment: Correct. However it has to be relative to the element it is being applied to.

Comment: MarsOne, your solution is exactly what I wanted. I had to edit the percentages slightly to get what I wanted but done the job! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MarsOne, As it goes I want to see how the background looks with a solid border line. I updated your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gZgLc/10/ What I am looking to try now is to rise this line so there the orange goes slightly higher. How would i do this?

Comment: I did not get what you meant.

Comment: So I updated the fiddle now to help me explain http://jsfiddle.net/gZgLc/11/ If i wanted the orange area to go further up so it also covers the 'home3' link for example, how would I do this?

Comment: Yes, i was doing but couldn't work out how to change that. Ok got that, last question can I adjust the width of the orange without adjusting the div itself? So still keeping a width of 958 px but the orange being only 900px wide for example?

Comment: @jfar_magnetik Simply answer is no.  You are filling that particular element with color, in your case a gradient.  It will fill the entirety of that element and no more or less than that.

Comment: Ok, at least I have a definitive answer on that. Thanks